# Flash Player installed with update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree is not working on YouTube on Chromium

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium, youtube

I was following the instructions on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash .

I run this in the terminal: `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install` and I get this output: `2014-07-26 01:56:02 (2,47 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/pepperflashplugin-nonfree.BqGj40yYUE/google-chrome-stable_36.0.1985.125-1_‌​amd64.deb’ saved [48386260/48386260]` and after restarting Chromium, Flash is not detected on YouTube and the HTML5 player is started.

Running `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status` prints the following lines in the terminal:

```
Flash Player version installed on this system : 14.0.0.145
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 14.0.0.145
```

But I still don't have Flash in Chromium on YouTube.

I have this entry in chrome://plugins page and Flash works normally on other websites:

http://i861.photobucket.com/albums/ab180/silviubogan/Screenshotfrom2014-07-26022752.png
[image]

I really need some help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your installation.
Youtube videos automatically start in Chrome and Chromium with HTML5 now by default and as far as I know there is nolonger a workaround or other way around this. You used to be able to opt-out of the html5 trial under the youtube settings. All I can suggest is to use firefox instead or switch to a different video site.

Comment: HTML5 should be better. I don't know why he would want to use Adobe Flash Player at all. This is the best answer.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste some people have issues with choppy video and cpu consumption with HD

Comment: Oh. I've never had such a problem. Also, if the video is choppy or not depends on the browser you are using because no plugins are in use. Are they choppy in Mozilla Firefox or WebKit browsers?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste I personally haven't had too much of an issue with this. At one point I wanted to take advantage of VDPAU and VAAPI accelerated decoding but Google chrome no longer allows netscape-like plugins so to me, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I want to use Flash because the HTML5 player is slow and unstable on my computer. On Firefox, YouTube still uses Flash and the Flash-based player is working well, it is stable and fast. But on Chromium I cannot replace the HTML5 player with the Flash-based player using the YouTube settings.

Comment: @silviubogan some people report better results toggling the hardware acceleration on or off see here on how to do that in chrome and chromium http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html Also, I had to add numerious openGL related packages to get full support.